# regex: extract power in calculation

Tags: python, regex

I need to get a list of powers from an expression, for example:

```py
'2 * x ** 3 + x ** -1 + x**4'
```

the expected result is

```
[3, -1, 4]
```

I have no idea how to do this, hence I cannot include any attempts what what I have tried.

---

I will be so grateful for any advice

Comment: By extracting power, do you mean just the exponents?

Comment: @Prometheus yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex `'\*\*\s*(-?\d+)'` as suggested in the the following code:

```
>> import re
>> s = '2 * x ** 3 + x ** -1 + x**4'
>> exponents = [int(exponent) for exponent in re.findall('\*\*\s*(-?\d+)', s)]
>>> exponents
[3, -1, 4]
```

Some explanation about the regex:

`\*\*` - You need to scape `**` because `*` in regex means any character.

`\s*` - after `**` you might need no white spaces or multiple spaces

`(-?\d+)` - it will allow you to have positive and negative integers.

Comment: I updated that just a couple of seconds you submitted that comment XD

Answer (score 3):

```py
[int(m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer('\*\*\s*(-?\d+)', t)]
```

The regexp here:
`\*\*` - two asterisks, you need to escape them with backslash as normally they have special meaning
`\s*` - any number of whitespace characters, unescaped asterisk means "any number"
`(-?\d+)` - a minus sign which might or might not be there followed one or more digits, the parentheses added so we can reference the content in `group(n)` query

The rest of it is to make it oneliner - constructing a list from the iterator of matches, casting to integer the part that we are interested in

Answer (score 1):

I used a little more than RegEx, works as well though:

```
import re

inp_str = '2 * x ** 3 + x ** -1 + x**4'
results = list(map(lambda x:int("".join(x)),re.findall(r"\*\*(-)?(\d+)",inp_str.replace(" ",""))))
print(results)
```

Comment: Why are the number and its sign in separate capture groups?

Comment: findall returns the captured groups, of which I have two: one for (-) and one for (\d)

Comment: Okay I see that you were joining the two groups together but it would be easier to just capture them together. Also your capture group for the number is only going to capture a single digit even though it matches multiple digits.

Comment: Edited the code, I misplaced the "+" sign, thanks for spotting the error!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

**[*]{2}** - twice asterisks
**\s?** - space, tab is or not
**-?** - sign (-) is or not
**\d** - number

```
import re

text = '2 * x ** 3 + x ** -1 + x**4'

res = re.findall( r'[*]{2}\s?-?\d', text) ## expected ['** 3', '** -1', '**4']
ans = [int(item[2:].strip()) for item in res] ## expected [3, -1, 4]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) to walks the abstract syntax tree and calls a visitor function for every node found

```
>>> source = "2 * x ** 3 + x ** -1 + x ** 4"
>>> import ast
>>> class ExponentsVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
...     exponents = []
...     def visit_BinOp(self, node):
...         self.visit(node.left)
...         self.visit(node.right)
...         if isinstance(node.op, ast.Pow):
...             if isinstance(node.right, ast.UnaryOp): # Right hand side is unary operator
...                 self.exponents.append(int(f"-{node.right.operand.value}"))
...             if isinstance(node.right, ast.Constant): # It's a constant.
...                 self.exponents.append(node.right.value)
... 
>>> visitor = ExponentsVisitor()
>>> visitor.visit(ast.parse(source))
>>> print(visitor.exponents)
[3, -1, 4]
```